# Solidity save complex object in the contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I have this usecase where I need to persist the following sample data in my contract.

```
{
    Linkage : {"4" : "1", "77" : "59", "5" : "64", "4" : "464", "455" : "364", "25" : "364", "25" : "164", "55" : "8684", "85" : "864"},
    UserId : "Some Id",
}
```

The dictionary is obviously expandable (root And Linkage).
I want to send the data and retreive it as an object (c# and Java style). So when I communicate from WEB3 I can pass json.
Is that possible?

This is where I got stuck...

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

contract Test{         
  struct UserProfile{       
    string UserId;
  }   

  UserProfile public Profile;

  function setProfile(UserProfile newProfile) public {
    Profile  = newProfile;
  }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass objects when initiating a transaction (yet). You can only pass in/return a `struct` through `internal` function calls ([see Solidity FAQ](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/frequently-asked-questions.html#can-a-contract-function-return-a-struct)).

You'll have to pass in your data using primitive types and add them to your internal `struct`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

contract Test { 
  struct UserProfile {
    string userId;
    mapping(uint256 => uint256) linkage;
  }   

  UserProfile public profile;

  function addLinkage(uint256 id, uint256 value) public {
    profile.linkage[id] = value;
  }
}
```

Note, if you want to pass in your linkages in bulk, you can use `addLinkage(uint256[] ids, uint256[] values)`.

Comment: Thanks, what about retrieving from the contract? Can I retrieve a nice json from it?

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize your object into a string, solidity has no object primitive and probably never will because of the nature of the Ethereum vm.